# Check integer is between two values in js

Tags: javascript

I am beginner web developer
I have this script:

```
let cupboardMinHeight = '300.00';
let cupboardMaxHeight = '400.00';
if(cupboardMinHeight <= $('.product-height').val() && cupboardMaxHeight >= $('.product-height').val()){
    console.log('ok');
} else {
    console.log('error');
}
```

When I have in  $('.product-height').val() == 300 - I have console.log error.

What's wrong?

How can I repair it?

Comment: You're comparing the values as strings, not as numbers. The string "300" is less than the string "300.00" because it has fewer characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

-Convert your input values and min-max values into integer or float and then try again.

```
let cupboardMinHeight = '300.00';
let cupboardMaxHeight = '400.00';
if(parseFloat(cupboardMinHeight) <= parseFloat($('.product-height').val()) && parseFloat(cupboardMaxHeight) >=parseFloat( $('.product-height').val())){
    console.log('ok');
} else {
    console.log('error');
}
```

Comment: as you define the min and max just right abve, you could just save them as floats and omit the `parseFloat(...)`

Comment: @MauriceNino Yes we can!.